# Why "Inception V3 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data" have 1001 outputs?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, entity

There are 6 pre-trained models on ImageNet in `NetModel`.

```
models={  "Inception V1 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data", 
          "Inception V3 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data", 
            "ResNet-152 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data", 
            "ResNet-101 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data", 
             "ResNet-50 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data", 
       "SqueezeNet V1.1 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data"}

nets = NetModel[#, "UninitializedEvaluationNet"] & /@ models;

Grid[Transpose@{models, nets}, Frame -> True]
```

Incption v3:

[image]

Why “Inception V3 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data” have 1001 outputs instead of 1000?

**Importing [the Inception v3 of MXNet](http://data.dmlc.ml/models/imagenet/inception-bn/),you can see it's have 1000 outputs.**

[image]

[image]

There is an original *[labels list](http://data.dmlc.ml/models/imagenet/synset.txt)*

[image]

And this is labels of wolfram's.

```
labels = First[Values[op[[1, "Outputs"]]]] // Normal;
```

[image]

I think that the extra one is `Other`, because it can't be found in the [labels list](http://data.dmlc.ml/models/imagenet/synset.txt).

Maybe transfer the original [labels list](http://data.dmlc.ml/models/imagenet/synset.txt) to `Entity`,then can find the difference.

Comment: There’s an extra noise class